# Is there a Brainfuck API?

Tags: brainfuck

So I stumbled upon a Brainfuck question, and I wondered, do any of its compilers/interpreters provide an API?

---

I'll make a separate question about *accessing* other APIs.

Comment: I do not think some interpreters have some, but brainfuck is simple to implement and you could add functionality to other characters other than the 8 characters.

Comment: Your question is actually, "Are there any libraries written for brainfuck", there's no API until there's something to interface with. Any general-purpose programming language has the potential to interface with any filesystem API, operating-system API, graphics API, network API. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @OregonTrail _Any general-purpose programming language has the potential..._ It does if the language allows at least access to portions of memory where the potential system API resides

Comment: Here's the other question: [does-some-brainfuck-compiler-intepreter-provide-a-mean-to-access-an-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740929/does-some-brainfuck-compiler-intepreter-provide-a-mean-to-access-an-api)

Comment: Damn this turned out to be a much more serious question than I thought..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure Brainfuck, there won't be anything, unless you write your own interpreter that uses specific chunks of memory for this.

One project that may interest you is [ajyoon/systemf](https://github.com/ajyoon/systemf), an interpreter where you can make Linux system calls using a special ninth character.

**EDIT:** I ended up answering the wrong question of the asker, this is more an answer to the other one.

Comment: Great, this answers at lease for sure my other question!

Comment: I'll wait a day or two, then I'll accept this answer if nothing else comes up.

Comment: _I ended up answering the wrong question_ At this point I'd say you answered this question as well, as nothing else has come up I guess you're right that "there won't be anything".