# Does some Brainfuck compiler/intepreter provide a mean to access an API?

Tags: brainfuck

Again, I stumbled upon a Brainfuck question, and I wondered, do any of its compilers/interpreters provide a way to access some API (the system one, or individual functions from a dll, and so on)?

---

*Note:* I already asked about APIs provided directly by the compiler/interpreter in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740581/is-there-a-brainfuck-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas Jager [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740765/2130006) , yes, [systemf](https://github.com/ajyoon/systemf) provides access to Linux syscalls.